# pandas cut generating less bins that specified

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

considering the dataframe below generated with the code as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# number of data points
n = 1000

# generate data - log-normal distribution
data = np.exp( np.random.randn(n)/2 ) 

# convert data (array) into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['counts'])
```

I am trying to group/aggregate the values under `df['counts']` into 40 equally sized bins (type should be `str` - later I want to plot this on the x axis of a histogram). In other words, I want to add a new column (`intervals`) to `df` with the interval to which each value (`counts`) belong. Below is the code that I used to generate `df['intervals']`:

```
df['intervals'] =  pd.cut(df['counts'], bins=40).astype('str').to_numpy()
```

But instead of getting 40 unique values under `df['intervals']` I am getting 36

```
len(df['intervals'].unique()) # returns 36
```

Does anyone know why I am getting 36 instead of 40, when this was the value passed to `pd.cut()`?

Comment: I think you dont have data in some bins

Comment: Print out the intervals and see which are missing. If an interval is empty, you won't see it with your code. Note you can get the bins returned if you set `retbins=True`, then you'll get all the bins not just the ones with values.

Comment: add python tag for better results

Comment: PDF of Log normal distribution goes to 0 very fast. When you cut the samples with equal buckets, it's very likely you would have some empty buckets, specially the higher ones.

Answer (score 0):

you can change its type later too, have you tried without astype('str') ?

Comment: df['intervals'] = pd.cut(df.counts, bins=5, retbins=True, labels=[0,1,2,3,4])   not sure but maybe this helps

Comment: I guess so, as pointed out by Dan the `retbins` should do